# Linq Find Partial Text Match - Included code returns duplicate and everything except what it should

Tags: c#, linq

I'm Trying to find a match (on a partial string) to see which Orders have not been processed.

The problem comes in line "`where a.OrderNo.IndexOf(b) >=0`"

It returns only the Already Processed - which is what I want to exclude.

```
Prefix2/OrderNo2 
Prefix1/OrderNo4
```

If I change it to  "where a.OrderNo.IndexOf(b) < 0" - then it returns duplicates of Items that are not in "AlreadyProcessed"

```
Prefix1/OrderNo1 
Prefix1/OrderNo1 
Prefix2/OrderNo2 
Prefix2/OrderNo3 
Prefix2/OrderNo3 
Prefix1/OrderNo4
```

How can I change the Linq to only show Items that still need to be processed?
Why is this happening (so that I can learn from this please)

```
void Main()
{
    RunThis();
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderNo;
    public int CustomerID;
}

private void RunThis()
{
    List<Order> o = new List<Order>()
    {
        new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix1/OrderNo1",CustomerID = 1},
        new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix2/OrderNo2",CustomerID = 7},
        new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix2/OrderNo3",CustomerID = 8},
        new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix1/OrderNo4",CustomerID = 12},
    };

    List<string> AlreadyProcessed = new List<string>()
    {
        "OrderNo2",
        "OrderNo4"
    };

    var ToBeProcessed = from a in o
                        from b in AlreadyProcessed
                        where a.OrderNo.IndexOf(b) >=0
                        select a.OrderNo;
   Console.WriteLine(ToBeProcessed);                            

}
```

Comment: With first two lines you are doing cross join, i.e. all pair combinations. Then you filter. Instead, do select from first, then filter using second list, like Rob suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>()
{
    new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix1/OrderNo1",CustomerID = 1},
    new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix2/OrderNo2",CustomerID = 7},
    new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix2/OrderNo3",CustomerID = 8},
    new Order { OrderNo = "Prefix1/OrderNo4",CustomerID = 12},
};

List<string> AlreadyProcessed = new List<string>()
{
    "OrderNo2",
    "OrderNo4"
};

var ToBeProcessed = orders.Where(o => !AlreadyProcessed.Any(ap => o.OrderNo.Contains(ap)))
                          .Select(o => o.OrderNo);
```